# How to convert timestamp into milliseconds in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to write a basic script that can read in a timestamp as a string and convert it into milliseconds. The timestamps I am working with are in minute:second.millisecond format.

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp_start = '54:12.123'

MSM = '%M:%S.%f'
zero = '00:00.000'

start_sec = (datetime.strptime(timestamp_start, MSM) - datetime.strptime(zero, MSM)).total_seconds()
start_ms = start_sec * 1000

print(start_ms)
```

This may be a round about approach, but I am first using datetime.strptime to get a datetime object, then subtracting by 0 in order to get a timedelta object, getting the total seconds of the timedelta object, and finally multiplying by 1000 to convert to milliseconds.

The above code works fine, except for any timestamps over an hour.

The issue that I am running into- the timestamps do not have an hour counter. For example: 1 hour, 5 minutes, and 30 seconds comes in as 65:30.000. datetime.strptime cannot recognize this format, as it only allows the minutes to be between 0 and 59.

How can I convert these timestamps into a format recognizable by datetime? Should I first get the timestamp into hour:minute:second:millisecond format? Keep in mind the end goal is to convert these timestamps into milliseconds. If there is a better approach any suggestions are more than welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'54:12.123'` isn't really a timestamp, but elapsed time, and there's no built-in method in Python that can deal with elapsed time with a format string like a timestamp format.

Since the format string in question is simply minutes and seconds separated by a colon, and seconds and milliseconds separated by a period, you can easily parse it with the `str.split` method:

```
def convert(msf):
    minutes, seconds = msf.split(':')
    seconds, milliseconds = seconds.split('.')
    minutes, seconds, milliseconds = map(int, (minutes, seconds, milliseconds))
    return (minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000 + milliseconds
```

so that `convert('54:12.123')` returns:

```
3252123
```

Comment: I had a feeling I was over complicating this. Perfect simple solution. Many thanks!